# Terminology in non-dimensionalization

Tags: dimensional-analysis

I am reading the paper "Enzyme kinetics for a two-step enzymic reaction
with comparable initial enzyme-substrate ratios" by C. L. Frenzen and P. K. Maini, where they nondimensionalize a system of differential equations.

They keep writing "unit order of magnitude" - what does this exactly mean?

For example, they write

"We nondimensionalize the dependent and independent variables
by letting $$S = \alpha s, Y = \pi y,$$
where $s$ and $y$ are dimensionsless variables, and $\alpha$ and $\pi$ are appropriate scales for the dependent variables.  We will endeavour to choose $\alpha$ and $\pi$ so that s and y are of **unit order of magnitude** ..."